# sed printing first 255 characters followed by entire line

Tags: regex, shell, sed, ksh, mks

I'd like to print the first 255 characters followed by entire line separated with a '^' character.

(Right now I'm testing with 10 characters at a time instead of 255.)
For example, this works fine with one huge problem:

```
cat myfile.txt | sed -e 's:^\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\)$:\1^\1\2:'
```

The problem is that some lines are very short, in which case I want to print the entire line twice separated with '^' character.

For example:

```
1234567890987654321
123
```

should print as:

```
1234567890^1234567890987654321
123^123
```

I don't really need to use sed, but it seems that sed should be able to do this - but any one line command would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only requires an almost trivial tweak to your `sed` script — you want to print up to the first N characters of a line, followed by the caret and the whole line, so you specify a range with a number and a comma before the upper bound:

```
sed -e 's:^\(.\{1,10\}\)\(.*\)$:\1^\1\2:'
```

or (cutting down on the number of backslashes and remembered strings):

```
sed -e 's:^.\{0,10\}:&^&:'
```

This adds the caret to what were empty lines; the version with `1,10` leaves empty lines empty.

Incidentally, Mac OS X `sed` requires a number before the comma; GNU `sed` follows tradition and does not require it, and treats the leading missing number as 0.  Portable code, therefore, will not write:

```
sed -e 's:^.\{,10\}:&^&:'
```

It will work with some, maybe most, but not all versions of `sed`.

Comment: The line without '0' before comma doesn't work in MKS either.

Comment: @Alex: that's interesting to know — thanks for the information.  Checking POSIX, the section on [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)'a and 'multiple matching characters' does not allow the value before the comma to be omitted, so there are grounds for omitting that option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using `awk` easily:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, 10) "^" $0}' file
1234567890^1234567890987654321
123^123
```

Comment: you could just leave the -v couldn't you and just have `n=10` inside the awk statement ?

Comment: Also you could just have `awk '{print substr($0, 1, 10) "^" $0}'` as substring will stop when it reaches the end of a line anyway :)